# Basic Home Rec Set Up

Tags: recording, daw, homerecording, studio

Newbie in desperate need of advice!

I want 24 bit studio quality recordings on a budget. Tough ask!
Mainly for Voice overs & vocals.

Here's my current plan:

SHURE SM57--> FETHEAD PREAMP--> SCARLETT 2i2 INTERFACE--> PC

Then output to USB MIXER (if poss?) with KNS8400 HEADPHONES for monitoring/mixing

I've added the mixer for 2 reasons:

1) Adding reverb/eq to the headphones without effecting the
    recording (I hate hearing a flat/dry vocal)

2) Linking a minidisc player to listen to backing tracks while
    recording vocals.

Do I actually need the mixer though or can all this be achieved on the DAW?

Or maybe a multitracker like the Zoom R8?

Lots of conflicting info out there so any experienced advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: The idea of monitors (cans here) is to be able to listen to *exactly* what is being sung/recorded. Reverb is usually put on at the end. By the way, this question, asking for gear recommendations, will probably be disallowed. Please read the 'dos & don'ts' of the site.

Comment: I'm not really sure what it is you're asking. If it's "can I do this with just a DAW?" the answer is "Yes."

Comment: And - SM57 is good for recording instruments, SM 58 is better for vox. Although for the same sort of money, a condenser mic would do a better job.

Comment: A 57 is fine for vox if you've got a pop-shield [read lingerie & coat-hanger] in place ;-) My issue was with "everything else"

Comment: I was asking if it was an effective first set up and if anyone could recommend an alternative for a tight budget.. Being new, I wasn't aware that you couldn't ask for gear recommendations. Seems a bit odd to me, but if thems the rules...

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are wanting to accomplish with your recording setup.  Do you want to record the backing tracks or any other input source along with the voice over or vocals?  What do you want to end up with after everything is recorded?  Just one vocal with no other music or sound?  Voice over something else that is audible in the final product?

Answer (score 2):

Good quality on a budget is routine these days.   You don't need the preamp and you probably don't need the mixer. You can do this all 'in the box'. Your DAW can put a reverb plugin as a channel insert that will be monitored but not recorded.   The Scarlett has ASIO drivers that will enable not-quite-realtime monitoring, but near enough.

SM58 is an SM57 plus the 'ball'.   For studio work you'll use a better, seperate pop filter anyway.  You'll get a brighter sound with a condenser mic., but plenty of good work has been done with a SM57!